# How to Simulate Ctrl+LeftMouse using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, powerpoint

Is there any way to simulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+LeftMouse command in Delphi ?

I want the pointer in PowerPoint viewer to be lazerpointer via code.

Comment: Call SendInput for this

Comment: thanks David Heffernan i use SendInput but it's not working.
it working only in edittext or memo whene i use edit1.setfocuse;

Comment: SendInput is working. It injects input into the foreground thread. Rather than faking input wouldn't it just be easier to use the supported mechanism, automation? Why do you feel compelled to fake input?

Comment: can u send me example how to use SendInput.

Comment: You don't need an example. You need a better idea of what you are doing. First of all you need to consider using the supported way to automate, namely UI automation. Why did you reject that? Why did you decide that input faking, that most brittle technique was your salvation?

Comment: i need to to turn a pointer to lazerpointer but there are no command in delphi do this
ppt.ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.PointerType:=ppSlideShowPointerPen;
ppt.ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.PointerColor.RGB:=ClRed;

Comment: That makes next to no sense to me. I give up.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is a way to simulate this.

What happens in PowerPoint when you press the combination of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+LeftMouseButton is that PowerPoint shows the mouse cursor which is by default hidden in presentation view. But instead of normal mouse cursor it displys the LaserPointer cursor.

So all you have to do is change the mouse pointer when that specific combination is used.
So search for topis on changing mouse cursor or on using custom image for mouse cursor.
There have been several question being asked on this topic already.